# add new row with jquery with rowid in input

Tags: jquery

Width this code i can add a new line to the table, and now i want do add also a line number to the input rowid (1,2,3,4,5,...) and if i remove one line, i need to recalculate the sequencial (I have little experience with jquery).
I've tryied this but without success:

```
$(table).delegate('.tr_clone_add', 'click', function() {
  function updateRowOrder(){
  $('tr.table-data').each(function(i){
        var row = $(this).text(i+1);
  });
}
  var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
  $(thisRow).clone().insertAfter(thisRow).find('#col1').val('0.00');
  $("#rowid").val(row);
});
```

This add the lines:

```js
var table = $('#table-data')[0];

$(table).delegate('.tr_clone_add', 'click', function() {
  var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
  $(thisRow).clone().insertAfter(thisRow).find('#col1').val('0.00');       
});

$(table).delegate('.tr_clone_del', 'click', function() {
  if ($('.tr_clone').length > 1) {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
    thisRow.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-data">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <input type="text" name="rowid[]" id="rowid" class="tbox_novo" value="1" style="text-align:center;">
      </td>
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <input type="text" name="col1[]" id="col1" value="0.00"></td>
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <button type="button" class="tr_clone_add">+</button>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <button type="button" class="tr_clone_del">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have made an attempt. Do you have a specific issue? I assume the row values should be sequential, ie. 1, 2, 3...? What happens when a row is deleted? Should all row numbers be recalculated, or should new rows start from the highest value? Also note that `delegate()` is deprecated and shouldn't be used, and `$($('#table-data')[0])` is redundant; just use `$('#table-data')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you're right, I forgot to mention what I tried and the expected result. I will adjust the question and supplement with the missing information.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are expecting the outcome to be by adding a 'line-number'? Are you wanting to update the `value` of  the `input#rowid` within the row to the line-number?

Comment: @Rory Mcrossan, thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing, you would end with many elements with repeated `id` and `id` must be unique.

Every time you add a new row, you should get the number of rows you already have and then increment by 1. With this value you set the id of the row you are creating.

When removing, get the id of the row you are removing and after the remove, run all rows and see the rows which the id is bigger than the id you removed, all rows with bigger id should have it's id decreased.

I also added an `id` to the `<tr>`, it makes easier to keep track of the id of each row

See below:

```js
var table = $('#table-data')[0];
var tbody = $(table).find('tbody')

$(table).delegate('.tr_clone_add', 'click', function() {
  let newId = $(".tr_clone").length + 1;
  var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
  let newRow = $(thisRow).clone();
  newRow[0].id = newId
  newRow.find('.tbox_novo').eq(0).attr("id","rowid_"+newId).val(newId);
  newRow.find("[name='col1[]']")[0].id = "row_"+newId+"_col1";
  tbody.append(newRow)
});

$(table).delegate('.tr_clone_del', 'click', function() {
  if ($('.tr_clone').length > 1) {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
    let id = parseInt(thisRow.id);
    thisRow.remove();
    $(".tr_clone").each((i, elem) => {
      if (parseInt(elem.id) > id){
        let newId = parseInt(elem.id) - 1;
        elem.id = newId
        $(elem).find(".tbox_novo").val(newId)
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-data">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone" id="1">
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <input type="text" name="rowid[]" id="rowid" class="tbox_novo" value="1" style="text-align:center;">
      </td>
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <input type="text" name="col1[]" id="col1" value="0.00"></td>
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <button type="button" class="tr_clone_add">+</button>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:3px;">
        <button type="button" class="tr_clone_del">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```